# Validate only uppercase words, ignore if a word continues with lowercase using REGEX

Tags: regex

I have the following paragraph:

`AUTOCAD is the best CAd program and it wins an AWARD for this.`

I want to use a regex which captures only `AUTOCAD`, `AWARD` and ignore `CAd` because it contains lowercase.

I wrote a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/wG0mW2/1) like:

```
\b[A-Z0-9]+(?![a-z]+)
```

but it takes also `C` from `CAd`... But I don't want it !

How to improve my regex ?

Comment: You can just use \b in the end, as you do in the beginning.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that the `\b[A-Z0-9]+(?![a-z]+)` pattern matches `C` and then tests `A` in `CAd`, but since the `A` is right before a lowercase letter `d`, the `(?![a-z]+)` lookahead makes the engine backtrack, step back and test `C` again to check it is not followed with a lowercase letter. Thus, the match is `C`.

[image]

To make the regex fail in this case, you need to either use a possessive quantifier `++` (or its equivalent atomic group `(?>[A-Z0-9]+)`) to prohibit backtracking into `[A-Z0-9]+` - [`\b[A-Z0-9]++(?![a-z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/pP0wL8/1) - or the [trailing `\b`](https://regex101.com/r/uB7sA0/1) as [Maria suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890484/validate-only-uppercase-words-ignore-if-a-word-continues-with-lowercase-using-r/38890628#comment65140984_38890484).